# An unexpected universe level

Tags: polymorphism, agda

Here is a definition similar to the one in `Data.List.All`:

```
open import Data.Vec

data All {α π} {A : Set α} (P : A -> Set π) : ∀ {n} -> Vec A n -> Set π where
  []ₐ  : All P []
  _∷ₐ_ : ∀ {n x} {xs : Vec A n} -> P x -> All P xs -> All P (x ∷ xs)
```

Why does `All` lie in `Set π`?

Agda version 2.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

Agda 2.4.2.4 and Agda 2.4.2.5 (the maintenance branch) report the expected error when `All` lives in `Set π`, but it is accepted by Agda 2.4.3 (the master branch).

Please reports this issue in the [Agda bug tracker](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues).

Comment: This is actually a consequence of forcing happening before universe checking. 'x' does not need to be stored in the constructor, so it doesn't count for the universe level.

Comment: So this is not a bug. @Saizan, could you give some actual rules or point to a paper that describes them?

Comment: Edwin Brady thesis describes forcing, I don't think there's a writeup on how this affects universes though